# DotNetCore Entity Framework many-to-many on the same table

Tags: c#, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

I am using DotNetCore 2, and I want to achieve a scenario where I have a single model, that can contain zero or more of the same models.

Consider the following scenario (for simplicity):

- An engine can consist of many parts (components)
- Each part can contain zero or more other parts (components)

I want to link these items as such:

**System**

```
Id    Name
----------------
1     Drive System
```

**Component**

```
Id    Name
----------------
1     Motor
2     Bearings
3     Couplings
4     Fixtures
```

With the many-to-many relationship between the `System` and the `Component` as such:

**SystemComponents**

```
SystemId    ComponentId
-------------------------
1           1
```

And many to many link on `Component` (for the lack of better a better name)

**ComponentComponents**

```
ParentId    ChildId
---------------------
1           2
1           3
1           4
```

So in the above scenario can be translated as *A Drive System has a component - Motor, and the motor has additional sub-components, 'Bearings', 'Couplings', and 'Fixtures'*

The `SytemComponent` relationship is working. For the `ComponentComponent` relationship, I have tried the following with my code-first migration:

**Component**

```
public class Component 
{
    public Component() 
    {
        SystemComponents = new Collection<SystemComponent>();
        ChildComponents = new Collection<Component>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Needs this for the Many to Many relationship
    public virtual ICollection<SystemComponent> SystemComponents { get; set; }

    // Any component can contain one or more existing components
    public virtual ICollection<Component> ChildComponents { get; set; }
}
```

**ComponentComponent** linking model:

```
public class ComponentComponent
{
    public int ParentComponentID { get; set; }
    public int ChildComponentID { get; set; }

    public Component ParentComponent { get; set; }
    public Component ChildComponent { get; set; }
}
```

With my `ComponentComponent` configuration:

```
public class ComponentComponentConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ComponentComponent> {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ComponentComponent> builder) {
        builder.ToTable("ComponentComponent");

        builder.HasKey(cc => new { cc.ParentComponentID, cc.ChildComponentID });

        builder.HasOne(cc => cc.ParentComponent)
            .WithMany(c => c.ComponentComponents)
            .HasForeignKey(cc => cc.ParentComponentID);

        builder.HasOne(cc => cc.ChildComponent)
            .WithMany(c => c.ComponentComponents)
            .HasForeignKey(cc => cc.ChildComponentID);
    }
}
```

When running the migration I get the following Error:

> Cannot create a relationship between 'Component.ComponentComponents' and 'ComponentComponent.ChildComponent', because there already is a relationship between 'Component.ComponentComponents' and 'ComponentComponent.ParentComponent'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.

How would I achieve such a relationship in Entity Framework in DotNetCore 2?

**EDIT**

I have uploaded a similar sample project to my github page:

https://github.com/JAspeling/Many-to-Many

Comment: My suggestion is Don’t do in one table.

Comment: How would you make a hierarchical structure then? You cant have 'x' amount of models for all the generations in a family tree...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is in your Component class. Instead of referencing to a collection of components it should look like this

```
public class Component 
{
    public Component() 
    {
        SystemComponents = new Collection<SystemComponent>();
        ChildComponents = new Collection<ComponentComponent>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Needs this for the Many to Many relationship
    public virtual ICollection<SystemComponent> SystemComponents { get; set; }

    // Any component can contain one or more existing components
    public virtual ICollection<ComponentComponent> ChildComponents { get; set; }
}
```

You need to make a reference to the mapping table.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many

Comment: You are right - but that wont fix the error I am getting when creating the migration - on the `ComponentComponent` builder, it is complaining about creating the relationship between the components, also note my other many-to-many relationship is working (`SystemComponents`) as expected

Comment: I've created a small sample project similiar to the one you've created. [Github repository](https://github.com/NQuirmbach/Many-to-many)

Comment: So the problem isn't the creation itself but only the migration?

Comment: Not really, it is more how you define the relations inside EF Core.

Comment: Awesome, I checked out the project and amended mine and it is working. Thank you so much!